# Flask Error not allowed to load local resource

Tags: html, mongodb, flask

I am trying to develop a flusk application which visualize data from mongodb. When I try to open index.html file I receive some errors as following:

Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/adil/project/static/lib/css/bootstrap.min.css
index.html:6

Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/adil/project/static/lib/css/keen-dashboards.css
index.html:7

Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/adil/project/static/lib/css/dc.css
index.html:8

Seems to a web server error but I run web server from "project" directory and these files are in this directory. I don't understand what is the problem?

Here are the references in index.html:

href="D:/adil/project/static/lib/css/bootstrap.min.css">

href="D:/adil/project/static/lib/css/keen-dashboards.css">

href="D:/adil/project/static/lib/css/dc.css">

Any help?

Comment: Could you provide more info? Would be helpful to see your index.html view and the way you configured Flask app object.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem on my own. I changed links as

href="../static/lib/css/bootstrap.min.css"> and it works